# Find local non-loopback ip address in Python

Tags: python

How can I find a list of local non-loopback IP addresses in Python (and stay platform-independent)?

Answer (score 2):

The [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces) package provides a platform-independent way of getting network interface and address info. The [ipaddress](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddress) package (standard in Python3, external in Python2) provides a handy `is_loopback` method.

It's not exactly trivial, but here is some code that worked at least once for me:

```
import netifaces
import ipaddress
from pprint import pprint


def get_local_non_loopback_ipv4_addresses():
    for interface in netifaces.interfaces():
        # Not all interfaces have an IPv4 address:
        if netifaces.AF_INET in netifaces.ifaddresses(interface):
            # Some interfaces have multiple IPv4 addresses:
            for address_info in netifaces.ifaddresses(interface)[netifaces.AF_INET]:
                address_object = ipaddress.IPv4Address(unicode(address_info['addr'], 'utf-8'))
                if not address_object.is_loopback:
                    yield address_info['addr']

pprint(list(get_local_non_loopback_ipv4_addresses()))
```

That `address_info` variable will also have `netmask` and `broadcast` keys you can access for more info.

The `IPv4Address` object also has `is_private` and `is_global` methods you can use for similar queries.